# Array filter is not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework. I am creating an intersection of two arrays that should return one or multiple elements if the conditions return true. However the last condition gets skipped for some reason.

```
const filterWithTags = response.docs.filter((doc: any) => doc.hasOwnProperty("tags") && doc.tags.length > 0 && (tags as any).filter((tag: any) => doc.tags.includes(tag)));
```

This code returns only elements that match the first two conditions `(hasOwnProperty and length> 0)`. I need it to continue to the `includes` condition as well.
Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `filter()` returns an array, even if that array is empty it will be *truthy*. You want to use `some()` instead of `filter()`.

Comment: Your last condition will always be true. You can check for the length of the filtered array or use `some` instead of filter.

Comment: @Lennholm you are right. I changed the second filter to some and now its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether `tags` contains some data:

```
const filterWithTags = response.docs.filter((doc: any) => doc.hasOwnProperty("tags") 
    && doc.tags.length > 0 
    && (tags as any).some((tag: any) => doc.tags.includes(tag)));
```

If `doc` has property `tags` and `doc.tags` has items, then we can check whether it contains some `tags` by `doc.tags`.

Comment: Wouldn't the last condidtion be always `true`? `.filter` returns an array and `!![] //true`. You might want to add `.length > 0`

Comment: I also thought that it should work. Still it should return only one element, it returns two. Basically it returns every element that has tags and tags has items.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler oops, sorry, you are right. I've updated my answer

Comment: @StepUp yes, that fixes the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your condition is always treated as `true` -`(tags as any) .filter ((tag: any) => doc.tags.includes (tag))`
Even if there are not any values ​​that meet conditions `filter` always returns an empty array. Any type of array treated as `true` in JS.